# Import errors when importing '@ionic/core''s specific method from a stencil component

Tags: javascript, ionic4, web-component, importerror, stenciljs

I want to change the behavior of an ionic4 web component.

I created a stencil component from [stencil-component-starter](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter) and copied the source of the component (ion-reorder in my case) from '@ionic/core/src/components'.

To make it work, I need to fix this import :  `import { getIonMode } from '../../global/ionic-global'`

I installed `@ionic/core` as dependence and tried many ways to import :

---

- `import { getIonMode } from '@ionic/core/dist/types/global/ionic-global';`

returns a TypeError :

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@ionic/core/dist/types/global/ionic-global". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

---

So I tried to directly import from `node_modules`

- `import { getIonMode } from '../../../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/global/ionic-global';`

but it returns a rollup import error :

```
Rollup: Unresolved Import Could not resolve '../../../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/global/ionic-global' from src/components/reorder/lazy_7lathtd3dfwla7hdtr7reg-reorder.js
```

---

I also tried to import the `Ionic/core` module : `import * as Ionic from '@ionic/core';`
But it doesn't provide the method `getIonMode()` that I need.

Perhaps I miss something in the import process ?

Any help or hint appreciated